# Add Item to Basket Filter vs Splice ReactJS Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-rails

I am an app where I a user can add a productItem to a Basket. At the moment if the user removes an item from the basket I am using .filter to remove the basketItem object from my basketItems array. I then setState to this array with the filtered item.

```
removeItem(msg, data) {
    let newStateItems = this.state.items.filter((i) => i.id != data.id); 
    this.setState({
        items: newStateItems
    });
    this.calculateTotals();
}
```

The issue however is that once I have removed an item and then go to add another Item, the new Item that is created shows as the old item until the page is refreshed - an example this app can be found [here](https://intense-fjord-39208.herokuapp.com/) and the [full repository](https://github.com/supert56/Checkout-React) is on github.

The add item call looks like this:

```
addItem(msg, data) {
    this.state.items.push(data);
    this.setState({
        items: this.props.items
    })
    this.calculateTotals();
}
```

How can I ensure that the correct item shows in the basket?

Comment: maybe you need add item something like this https://jsfiddle.net/7og8ztLz/

Comment: Use `concat` instead `push` in react. `push` mutates values. But React works with immutable data (It works with mutable data, but I don't recomend you to look for problems)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you have two problems:

1. You're calling *calculateTotals* synchronously, i.e. before the state object is updated
2. You're setting the state to be *this.props.items*

I would recommend the following:

```
removeItem(msg, data) {
    let newStateItems = this.state.items.filter((i) => i.id != data.id); 
    this.setState({
        items: newStateItems
    }, this.calculateTotals);
}
```

AND

```
addItem(msg, data) {
    let newStateItems = this.state.items.concat([data]); 
    this.setState({
        items: newStateItems
    }, this.calculateTotals);
}
```

Notice how *this.calculateTotals* is now sent to setState, which then calls it after updating the state, but also that *addItem* now sets the state using a modified list and not the *props* as it was before (I assume this was a minor typo, but it probably contributed).

Here is the documentation for setting state: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate